# Suppress odepack warnings in scipy.integrate.ode

Tags: python, scipy

I'm currently trying to perform Bayesian inference on a (stiff) differential set of equations that is solved using `scipy.integrate.ode`, with either `lsoda` or `vode` as solver routines. The Bayesian inference procedure involves random sampling of the parameter space (more precisely: the posterior distribution), and for each set of parameters a forward simulation is run, so that the ODE is solved many hundreds of times over for each inference.

Now, due to the random nature of the sampling process, certain combinations of parameters cause the ODE solver to go bananas and terminate prematurely. This is all fine and accounted for, but what thoroughly annoys me is the constant stream of warnings thrown to `stdout`. Example:

```
lsoda--  warning..internal t (=r1) and h (=r2) are  
   such that in the machine, t + h = t on the next step  
   (h = step size). solver will continue anyway  
  in above,  r1 =  0.2821503005995D+01   r2 =  0.2168780116940D-15
```

Normally the solver goes quiet after raising a few of such warnings, but because the solver is re-initiated hundreds/thousands times over, it keeps spitting out warnings like a llama on a warm day.

**My question**: is there any way to silence these warnings?

Comment: [A pull request](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/pull/8635) was recently merged in the scipy development branch that might fix your problem.  To use it, you'll have to install the development version of scipy, or wait for scipy 1.1.0 to be released in a few weeks.

Comment: Such coincidence. Thanks for the heads-up